# JS Removing Labels Font Style - MVC3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a label which displays the number of characters used in a textbox.  When the page first loads it looks fine as it is small and in italics.  I am using Bootstrap for that styling.

```
<label id="lblCharactersRemaining"><small><em>0 Out Of 255 Characters</em></small></label>
```

My JavaScript checks and updates the text in this label with the number of characters a user enters, this also works fine.

The problem is that each time the JS activates the styling goes back to the default MVC type.  How can I make sure that when the JS executes that it doesn't remove the Bootstrap styling?

My JS is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var maximumLength = '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaximumTextBoxLength"]';
        if (document.getElementById("ObjectTextBox")) {
            var txtbox = document.getElementById("ObjectTextBox");
            txtbox.onkeyup = function () { IsMaxLength(this); };
        }
        function IsMaxLength(objTxtCtrl) {
            if (objTxtCtrl.getAttribute && objTxtCtrl.value.length > maximumLength) {
                objTxtCtrl.value = objTxtCtrl.value.substring(0, maximumLength);
            }
            if (document.all) {
                document.getElementById('lblCharactersRemaining').innerText = (objTxtCtrl.value.length) + ' Out Of ' + maximumLength + ' Characters';
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('lblCharactersRemaining').textContent = (objTxtCtrl.value.length) + ' Out Of ' + maximumLength + ' Characters';
            }
            if (objTxtCtrl.value.length == 0) {
                document.getElementById('lblCharactersRemaining').textContent = '0 Out Of ' + maximumLength;
            }
       }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
    function IsMaxLength(objTxtCtrl) {
        if (objTxtCtrl.getAttribute && objTxtCtrl.value.length > maximumLength) {
            objTxtCtrl.value = objTxtCtrl.value.substring(0, maximumLength);
        }
        if (document.all) {
            $('#lblCharactersRemaining').html('<small><em>' + objTxtCtrl.value.length + ' Out Of ' + maximumLength + ' Characters</em></small>');
        }
        else {
            $('#lblCharactersRemaining').html('<small><em>' + objTxtCtrl.value.length + ' Out Of ' + maximumLength + ' Characters</em></small>');
        }
        if (objTxtCtrl.value.length == 0) {
            $('#lblCharactersRemaining').html('<small><em>0 Out Of ' + maximumLength + '</em></small>');
        }
   }
```

Every time you launch the function, it deleted the tags '`small`' and '`em`', so just add them...

UPDATE : PS : Using Jquery language...

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENT :**

**BOOTPLY :** http://bootply.com/106485

**CODE :**

***JS :***

```
$('button.jquery').on('click', function(){
    $('#lblCharactersRemaining').html('<small><em>0 Out Of 85200</em></small>');
});

$('button.nojquery').on('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('lblCharactersRemaining').innerHTML = '<small><em>0 Out Of 666</em></small>';
});
```

***HTML :***

```
<label id="lblCharactersRemaining"><small><em>0 Out Of 255 Characters</em></small></label>

<button class="jquery">Change label with jquery</button>
<button class="nojquery">Change label without jquery syntax</button>
```

Comment: When I've tried that it has output the tags in the text.   So it appears as `<small><em>12 Out Of 255</em></small>` on the page.

Comment: Still no joy.  When I change the script to the above it doesn't do anything now.  Could I be missing a reference to Jquery?  I've never (knowingly) used it before.